# Show that transformation mediated by $F$ is canonical

Tags: homework-and-exercises, coordinate-systems, hamiltonian-formalism, phase-space

I am trying to solve this problem

> If for some phase transformation $(p,q) \rightarrow (p',q')$ it holds $\sum p_i\dot{q_i} - H = \sum \dot{p_i}q_i + p_i\dot{q_i} - \dot{p_i'}q_i' - H' + \frac{d}{dt}F(\textbf{p}, \textbf{p'},t)$ where $H, H'$ are Hamiltonians in the respective coordinates, transformation mediated by $F$ is canonical.

Where above, for simplicity existence of the mediation by $F$ was omitted to prove.

Now, I am having difficulty with taking partial derivatives, in the sense that any 2 pair of coordinates is enough to describe the others by putting them inside the partials of $F$, and I get confused what is really independence between variables because pairwise they can be independent. I hope this makes sense.

The transformation mediated by $F$ can be shown to be:
$\frac{\partial}{\partial p'}F = q'; \frac{\partial}{\partial p}F = -q$

Anyway, for testing I came up with the following choice of $F:$ (and say there is only 1 degree of freedom)
$$F = p^2p'^2$$

so that $q = -2p{p'}^2, q' = 2p^2p'$ (hopefully this is valid)

then above condition holds with $H = H'$.

But, to show canonicity, $\{q', p'\} = 0$ was needed but I think $\frac{\partial p'}{\partial q'} = 0$ is not true (which is the one of the factors in the second term of Poisson bracket)

How can we show it is canonical?